# Is there a way to avoid multiple instances of code when mutating itself?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is written in kotlin but I'm pretty sure it's almost the same in java.

```
something.setOnClickListener {
            availableReportRecycler.isActivated = !availableReportRecycler.isActivated
            if (availableReportRecycler.isActivated) availableReportRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else availableReportRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

Is there a way in kotlin/java to simplify this code?

I feel like it should be able to reduce it to something like (pseudo code):

```
something.setOnClickListener {
   availableReportRecycler.visibility = 
      {availableReportRecycler.isActivated = !self}  ? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE
}
```

I've brute forced all kinds of combinations after not finding anything relevant online and still cant get it to work.

How beautiful can you make it?
Best answer gets a virtual beer and an "I'm alright" sticker!

Comment: You seem to identify "beautiful" with "short". However, it is better to strive for clarity.

Comment: For me, the two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: True, they are not strictly exclusive, but often enough the shortest possible program is also somewhat cryptic. For instance in your example I would not combine toggling `isActivated` with the assignment to `visibility`. (Although this can be done and makes for shorter code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary part of the presented code that is far from being pretty is the repetition of the long `availableReportRecycler` name. Combining scoping function `with` from the Kotlin standard library with imports and `if` expression lets us make this code much cleaner without making it harder to understand:

```
something.setOnClickListener {
    with (availableReportRecycler) {
        isActivated = !isActivated
        visibility = if (isActivated) VISIBLE else GONE
    }
}
```

You can apply further scoping function like `also` to avoid repeating `isActivated` on the second statement, but, for my taste, it would not make this particular code better.

Answer (score 1):

I think Roman Elizarov has a good approach. But if you want to link activated and visibility 
you might want to consider overriding the `setActivated` like this:

```
class AvailableReportRecycler(context: Context) : View(context) {
    override fun setActivated(value : Boolean) {
        super.setActivated(value)
        visibility = if(value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

This way you link the visibility to the state of activated. and you can call it like this:

```
something.setOnClickListener {
     availableReportRecycler.isActivated = !availableReportRecycler.isActivated
}
```

Isn't object-orientation beautiful? :)